# HP Proliant Gen 8 disks stalling

Tags: hp-proliant, windows-10

My config is a HP ProLiant MicroServer Gen8 (Intel Xeon E3-1220L v2, 16GB) with one HPE 659337-B21 Harddisk (3.5", 7200RPM, 1000GB) with Windows 10 pro.

Multple times a day the machine stalls for like an hour: The disk starts to spin like crazy within that time, sometimes more, sometimes less. The OS is almost not responsive at all: Can't ALT TAB, can't start Task Manager, CTRL ALT DEL has no effect either. After that the system gets responsive again.

I suspect a hardware / setup / disk / controller problem as the root cause. But how can I approach the troubleshooting to narrow down the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to check the disks?

Comment: Not yet, how would you do that precisely? With onboard windows utilities?

Comment: Have you checked your logs ?

Comment: Assuming you have backups, definitely run a disk check (Windows Checkdisk). Otherwise, don't run anything that will perform large iterations and IO operations on the disks. If the disks are dying, the more IO operations put through them could potentially reduce your chances of recovering data. Let us know if you have backups - gives more flexibility for recovery options :P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far. The windows logs show nothing worth to mention. Checkdisk found no problems either.

Comment: Backups are present too.